# Ansible - Change Exact IP address

Tags: replace, ansible, ip-address, shorewall

Assume that shorewall rules config contain

```
ACCEPT  net:1.234.5.253 all tcp 3306        
ACCEPT  net:1.234.5.2   all tcp 80      
ACCEPT  net:1.234.5.2   all tcp 80      
ACCEPT  net:1.2.3.4,1.234.5.22,1.1.1.1  all tcp 3306
```

I want replace them with ansible

```
  - name: Replace old ips in /etc/shorewall/rules
    replace:
      path: /etc/shorewall/rules
      regexp: '{{ oldip }}'
      replace: '{{ newip }}'
      backup: 'yes'
```

Variables are

```
  vars:
    oldip: 1.234.5.2
    newip: 100.100.100.100
```

Im getting output which is correct, but im expecting replace EXACT match of ip not this output

```
ACCEPT  net:100.100.100.10053   all tcp 3306        
ACCEPT  net:100.100.100.100 all tcp 80      
ACCEPT  net:100.100.100.100 all tcp 80      
ACCEPT  net:1.2.3.4,100.100.100.1002,1.1.1.1    all tcp 3306
```

Is there any way how to solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you provide, you could use anchors:

```
- name: Replace old ips in /etc/shorewall/rules
  replace:
    path: /etc/shorewall/rules
    regexp: '(\D){{ oldip }}(\D)'
    replace: '\1{{ newip }}\2'
    backup: 'yes'
```

Search for a non-digit, followed by the old IP, followed by another non-digit.

Replace with the first non-digit found, followed by the new IP, and the second capture group.

If there's any risk of the backreferences being misinterpreted (for example, if your new IP were hardcoded rather than in a variable), use `\g` to avoid confusion between `\1` and `\1100` :

```
    replace: '\g<1>100.100.100.100\2'
```

Comment: FWIW. `(\D)` is simpler.